# Kubernetes wait on pod/job

Tags: kubernetes

Upon push I want to create a single kaniko build job, it currently works but after the job is finished it shows:

```
kaniko-5jbhf                  0/1     Completed   0          9m13s
```

Yet when I run the following it just pauses indefinitely:

```
kubectl wait --timeout=-1s --for=condition=Completed pod/kaniko
```

My question can be summarized in 2 parts:
1). How can I wait for a pod/job to finish? 2). How can I remove the job after it has finished?

I have tried ttlSecondsAfterFinished but enabling feature gates in the cluster is problematic and there is no example of how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `wait` to evaluate the state of a resource, you need to correctly identify it. For the second snippet, you need to provide the *pod id* instead of the job name: `kubectl wait --timeout=-1s --for=condition=Completed pod/kaniko-5jbhf`. However, the syntax seems correct for calling the job itself as `job/kaniko`.

[For further reference](https://hackernoon.com/kubectl-tip-of-the-day-wait-like-a-boss-40a818c423ac) on `wait`.

Now, for the `Job` deletion, if you don't want to use the feature gates, I think you can either [access the API programmatically](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#programmatic-access-to-the-api) to locate and delete finished `Jobs` or make them dependant on a parent object that deletes them in cascade. For `Jobs` specifically, there's only `CronJobs`. The downside is that `CronJobs` are meant to be [*time-scheduled* objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/), this means that you need to start designing on a *time-based object*.

Consider that by design, `Jobs` are meant to stay after the completion [to preserve data related to what happened while they're processing data](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion). Also, from *v1.12*, they're also designed to delete themselves, meaning that enabling these feature gates is probably the most straightforward way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The indefinite waiting is probably caused by using incorrect condition names. I had the same trouble. I eventually checked the source code and came up with the following

```
$ kubectl wait --for=condition=Complete job/my-job
```

and

```
$ kubectl wait --for=condition=Failed job/my-job
```

The correct naming can also be found as follows:

```
$ kubectl explain job.status.conditions.type
KIND:     Job
VERSION:  batch/v1

FIELD:    type <string>

DESCRIPTION:
     Type of job condition, Complete or Failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to wait for a `Job` to be either `Completed` or `Failed`, you can do the following:

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pod --selector=job-name=YOUR_JOB_NAME --timeout=-1s
kubectl logs --follow job/YOUR_JOB_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

To wait until a resource (like Deployment, Job, etc.) has **rolled out**, and all its objects are ready, run:

```
kubectl rollout status {Resource Type} {Resource name}
```

For example:

```
  $ kubectl rollout status deployment my-app

    Waiting for rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
    Waiting for latest deployment config spec to be observed by the controller loop...
    replication controller "my-app" successfully rolled out
```

Another way is to **wait for a specific pod**, by id, or even better - by label. For example:

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pod -l app=my-app
```

Note that if the pod was created with `kubectl run my-app ...` (and not with "create deployment"), the label would probably be `run=my-app`

Answer (score 1):

You should not wait on pods, wait works for jobs. I am not sure that `Completed` should be the condition - `complete` seems to work at least locally for me, so it should be
`kubectl wait --timeout=-1s --for=condition=complete job/${job_name}`

And besides that, unless you want to wait for it indefinitely, check that you are specifying `--timeout=-1s`, negative one, as timeout.
`kubectl wait` takes any negative timeout param as "wait for a week".

From Kubernetes [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait):

```
    The length of time to wait before giving up. 
    Zero means check once and don't wait, negative means wait for a week.
```